# Google Webmaster Stats

Tags: php, google-search-console

### Google Webmaster Stats

I'd want to show some stats much like the ***Google Webmaster Tools*** with the following things:

- crawl stats,
- links to your site,
- structured data,
- etc.

What is the way to get these stats from Google Webmaster Tools? I searched for it, but couldn't find a sufficient answer. Thanks a lot for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A starting point is to check the [Google Webmaster Tools API - Developers Guide](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/), where pretty much all your answers are covered. Unfortunately, this only outputs information about domains you have verified yourself through the GWT. **It does not work on third party domains!**

That said, there are a plethory of tools, API's (see [Programmableweb.com](http://www.programmableweb.com/), [Mashape](http://www.mashape.com/)) and other code snippets on the web (such as the splendid [SEOStats by eyecatchup](https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats)) that in some form enables you to put together your own set of domain information tool.